# How can I list all installed applications including those installed in per-user context?

Tags: windows, deployment, msi, windows-installer

I can run `wmic product` to get a list of all installed software.  This command will list any software installed in the system context, or per-user context for the logged in user.  However, this command does not list any software which was installed **by another user** in per-user context.

Is it possible to get a list of all installed software on a computer, including the software which was installed by another user in per-user context?

I am sure I could enumerate through the HKCU registry keys for each user, but is there a simple command line to accomplish this instead?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a third party application, or does it have to be done using command line/powershell?

Comment: Ideally it would be a built-in command or powershell, but I suppose I am not opposed to a third-party utility.

Answer (score 0):

These may not be the most ideal for your use, but it is easier than probably running/designing a script.

First Place: **Belarc**

- [Belarc](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) provides a wonderful suite of tools aimed at 'license management'.  In just about any application for upgrading computers for users I have used these tools to determine software originally installed as well as the CD Keys for this.
- I can't attest to per user capability, but the personal use version is a free license.  So, you can test it out and see if it does what you need.

**Honorable Mentions:**

1. N-Able

   - This product by Solarwinds is enterprise ready and deploy capable.  Best of all, it's fairly budget friendly with a reasonable minimum cost.  It does a lot of things including providing a free enterprise grade anti virus.
   - For your purposes, though, it provides a list of every piece of software and hardware on the installed computer.  Best of all, you can push this software out remotely so you don't have to go to each computer individually.
   - Not reccommended for small scale needs, but an excellent choice for a large scale environment with many remote offices and a decent budget for these kinds of tools.
2. Labtech

   - Much like N-Able, this product provides all the same features including a full list of installed software.
   - I can't attest to the pricing model of this one, though.  So, it gets the lowest seating on the list solely because I have no idea on the costs (Used, but never had to buy it).
3. Spiceworks (Courtesy of @ToddWilcox)

   - Free network wide monitoring.
   - Can report back on all software installed across the network to a centralized installation server.
   - Several other monitoring options as well as many operating systems supported.

Comment: I would add [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/free-pc-network-inventory-software/), which is free, runs on a server, and can scan and report back on software installed across the whole network. We have it and it works fairly well.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Good catch, I did forget about Spiceworks.  I will add that one in as well.

Comment: @BrandynBaryski I appreciate the response and the detail, but I just tested Belarc.  It does list software installed in the system context, however, it does not list software installed in a per-user context.  I am specifically asking for something that will list per-user installed software for all users.